# Netlogo giving attribute value of agent based on value of patch and slider parameter (2)

Tags: slider, patch, netlogo

So, just like my previous question I want to make buycapability attribute of agents. This attribute consists of three categories which are high middle and low. There are three threshold values of this buycapability which are >= 50 (low), 50>m<=100 (middle) and >100 (high) that are determined by two sliders. Besides, agent stays on a patch that has land-price attribute. So, the buycapability will be determined by land-price and threshold values. For example, if the land-price of agent's patch is greater than 100(slider buycapability_high value) then agent's buycapability is high and so on just like in procedure to-set-income-resident. Below code is the code that I use so far, to create or make the buycapability categorization. But unfortunately, the result of this code is all buycapability attribute af agents are low, there is no other than that. Even though the land-price is greater than 100 which should be high but it's not. Please help me to find what might wrong with the code or other possibility. 
[image: interface]

```
patches-own [value
            empty]
turtles-own [income
            myHouses
             ]
to setup
ca


;;Check inputs
let total-prob prob-rendah + prob-sedang + prob-tinggi 
if (total-prob != 100 )
[
  print (word "totalprob must sum to 100, but instead sum to " total-prob)
  stop
]

create-turtles 100
[setxy random-pxcor random-pycor
 set shape "default"
set size 1

;set-income
set-income2]

ask patches [set value random-normal 10 6

set pcolor brown + value
set empty true]


end

to set-income2

if[value] of patch-here > buycapability_middle and [value] of patch-here <= buycapability_high [set income "middle"]
if[value] of patch-here > buycapability_high [set income "high"]
if[value] of patch-here <= buycapability_middle [ set income "low"]

end

to go 
let target []

ask turtles with [income = "low"]
[ let potential-target1 patches with [value < buycapability_middle and any? turtles-here = false] 
 set target min-one-of potential-target1 [value]
  pen-down move-to target ask patch-here [set empty false]]

 ask turtles with [income = "middle"]
 [ let potential-target2 patches with [value < buycapability_high and value > buycapability_middle and any? turtles-here = false] 
 set target min-one-of potential-target2 [value]
 pen-down move-to target ask patch-here [set empty false]]

 ask turtles with [income = "high"]
 [ let potential-target3 patches with [value > buycapability_high and any? turtles-here = false] 
 set target min-one-of potential-target3 [value]
 pen-down move-to target ask patch-here [set empty false]]

 end
```

Comment: I don't think this can be your actual code, because this doesn't even compile. Can you post your actual code?

Comment: you mean... the whole code? okay, I will post it.

Comment: It doesn't have to be the whole code. Just actual code that actually compiles. I know this doesn't compile because for example `if [land-price] ...` isn't valid syntax.

Comment: @SethTisue tisue I've just added the code, but it's simple version without map and empirical data. This code still show the same result, the whole agent's income attribute are low.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

is that already your actual code?

I think that is because you put the patch's value initialization after the `set-income`. 
That way, every time you setup, the patches's value that function `set-income` will get is 0 since you haven't set the value yet.

try putting the `set-income`at the end of the code

```
to setup
  ....
  ....
  ask patches [
    set value random-normal 6 10
    ...
    ...
  ]
  set-income2
end
```

hope this helps.

Comment: That's the code without map and historical data set and thank you so much, yes it was the problem cause, the sequence. I didn't notice that. I have changed the order and then it just worked as I wanted to. Hehe I have been thinking so many possibilities  except the sequence. Thanks again I can continue completing my model further.